# Sending HTTP POST request with Swift to Discord Webhook results in Response Error

Tags: ios, discord, xcode11, swift5

I'm trying to create a URL Request in Swift to send an HTTP POST request to a Discord Webhook, and the request completes in a failure defined as 'responseProblem'. I'm not sure where the response problem is originating from.

Discord should technically be able to accept HTTP requests, and a bunch of research into the issue has led me nowhere. I've worked with Discord webhooks before, but I've never played around with this kind of stuff before, so I'm kinda stuck for what I should do now.

```swift
import Foundation

enum APIError:Error {
    case responseProblem
    case decodingProblem
    case encodingProblem
}


struct APIRequest {
    let resourceURL: URL

    init(endpoint: String) {
        let resourceString = "<discord-webhook-url-removed-for-privacy>"
        guard let resourceURL = URL(string: resourceString) else {fatalError()}

        self.resourceURL = resourceURL

    }

    func save (_ messageToSave:Message, completion: @escaping(Result<Message, APIError>) -> Void ) {

        do {
            var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: resourceURL)
            urlRequest.httpMethod = "POST"
            urlRequest.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
            urlRequest.httpBody = try JSONEncoder().encode(messageToSave)

            let dataTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { data, response, _ in
                guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpResponse.statusCode == 200, let
                    jsonData = data else {
                        completion(.failure(.responseProblem)) // <<< 'responseProblem' is outputted in console as the error
                        return
                }

                do {
                    let messageData = try JSONDecoder().decode(Message.self, from: jsonData)
                    completion(.success(messageData))
                } catch {
                    completion(.failure(.decodingProblem))
                }

            }
            dataTask.resume()
        } catch {
            completion(.failure(.encodingProblem))
        }

    }

}
```

When I run this Swift program, I expected it to send a request to the Discord Webhook to send a message into it's designated channel. However, the only error outputted into the console is `responseProblem`. Please let me know if there is anything further I need to add to get the root cause of the problem (I'm still semi-fresh to Swift, and I normally work with JavaScript, so I'm not sure how to properly debug in Swift and Xcode.)

Swift app is built in iOS 12.2 because Xcode doesn't like this stuff in iOS 13

Comment: Which one of the guard failed? `httpResponse`? `httpResponse.statusCode`? `jsonData`? There are 3 reasons to enter the failure case, at least give us which one failed. Print each one: `response`, and `data` (or `String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)`)

Comment: @Larme I printed both response and data, and the response has a Status Code of 400 nested in it.

Here is the output: 

Optional(<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x600001136040> { URL: https://discordapp.com/api/webhooks/<removed-for-privacy> } { Status Code: 400, Headers {
}

(I removed the headers as they could not fit in this comment box)

Comment: HTTP Error 400 is Bad Request. "I've worked with Discord webhooks before": Well maybe your params, your header, etc. anything in your `URLRequest` that is missing or wrong. Check the doc? Are the param in the httpBody as JSON? Not URL encoded form, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

This is a simplified version of how I post to a Discord webhook with Swift. From your post I can't see how you're converting your custom Message struct into a JSON dictionary, but you need at least the key/value pair for "content" to successfully post a Discord Webhook. And of course the posts can be customized in many other ways (with a custom "username" etc.).

```
    var messageString: String = ""

    guard let url = URL(string: "your-full-discord-webhook-url") else { return }
    let messageJson: [String: Any] = ["content": messageString]
    let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: messageJson)
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "content-type")
    request.httpBody = jsonData
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request)
    task.resume()
```